# Using comparison operators, such as '!=' and '==', with generics constrained as value in C#

Tags: c#, generics, constraints, value-type

I have the following code:

```
class Foo<T> where T : struct
{
    private T t;
    [...]
    public bool Equals(T t) { return this.t == t; }
}
```

When I try to compile, it gives me the following error:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'

Why can't it be done? If the constraint was `where T : class` it would have worked. But I need it to be value type because in my implementation this generic will always be an enum.

What I am doing to circunvent the situation is using `Object.Equals()` method. Will it ensure the correct behavior all the time, since I am only comparing between T?

Comment: It is a bit late here in my timezone. Tomorrow I'll check the other answers and mark the accepted one. Thanks all!

Comment: Remember you can use `ReferenceEquals` to check for reference equality, which is what `==` usually does (unless I'm mistaken or it has been overridden).

Comment: @Svish - `ReferenceEquals` always returns `false` when passed value types, which is what `T` is constrained to here.

Comment: @Earwicker: Oh, right... *facepalm* :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an unpopular limitation of the constraints system. You cannot constrain a value type according to specific operations on it unless they are defined in an interface. So you cannot constrain for operator definitions, as they will not be defined on all value types, and the `struct` constraint allows any value type to be passed in.

```
struct A { }
```

That has no `==` defined, and yet your constraint says you'd be happy to accept it. So you cannot use `==`.

The reason its different for reference types is because there is always a definition of `==` available for them (identity comparison).

The implementation of `==` on `enum` is close enough to the implementation of `Equals` that your workaround is fine.

Compare with the situation for `>` with numeric types! No such workaround there. The standard numbers have no interface with methods like `GreaterThan`, etc.

Comment: Hmm, I see... Thanks for all the clarification!

Comment: On your reference type note, keep in mind that `==` can't be *overridden*, but can be *overloaded*.  Therefore a definition of `==` on a specific reference type will only be called when the operator is used on arguments statically known to derive from that type.  With just a `class` constraint on a generic method, this means that `==` is *always* identity comparison.

Comment: @kvb - You're right, I've removed the "unless overridden" given that was both poorly worded and irrelevant here anyway.

Comment: Your last section on `>` is entirely correct. But what you _can_ do is constrain `where T : struct, IComparable<T>` and then use `CompareTo` instead. But certainly `CompareTo` behaves differently than `>` if an operand is `NaN` for types `double` and `float`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html) by Jon Skeet and Marc Gravell. It describes an implementation of "generic operators" using Linq expressions. The actual implementation is available in [the MiscUtil library](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/)

Comment: It's a great article, but surely overkill when merely comparing for equality - the .NET framework already provides a universal method name for that, `Equals`, so it can be used on all types. Hence the OP's workaround is fine and guaranteed to work for any other type arguments too. For more number-related operators, the Linq expressions approach is very clever, but it does introduce a type hole.